# Ternary relationship with history tracking

Tags: database-design, erd

I have the following entities

```
Procedure -> id_procedure , desc_procedure .
Status   -> id_status ,   desc_status .
Subprocess -> id_subprocess , desc_process .
```

The rules are:

- 1 procedure can have 1 status
- 1 status can belong to N procedures
- 1 subprocess can have N procedures
- 1 procedure can belong to N subprocedures
- 1 subprocess can have 1 status
- 1 status can belong to N subprocess

[image]

This ternary relationship is built in this way because I need to track the status of a procedure that belongs to a subprocess.

The full ER diagram (in Spanish)

[image]

Now I need to model these requirements:

Need to track changes on the status of the "has" relationship with a time_stamp and a old_Status and and new_status.

I *think* I need another relationship like this:

```
Change : id_subprocess , old_status , new_status , time_stamp
```

How could I model this without adding more fields to my current "has" relationship. Or if I *need* to add these fields I would highly appreciate your comments.

A procedure can be connected to multiple subprocess at the same time. The subprocesses and processes share the same status. A process can be "student inscription" , a subprocess "get documentation" , "medical test ". A status could be "Active" , "Paused" , "Finished".